# "came" or "comes" in the "when" block of the future perfect continuous in the past

Tags: tense-agreement, time-reference

In some Russian book about the English grammar I have read the example of the sentence for the *future perfect continuous in the past*:

> I said that I should have been writing a letter for an hour when he came.

In my opinion the  word "comes" must be instead of "came" at this case. But another Russian man told me the sentence is incorrect completely...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what the temporal relationship exists between "writing" and *his* coming.  As the sentence is written, since it starts with Past Indefinite "I said", then "he came" likely relates to "my saying", and not "writing".  Similar to

> I said (to him) *something* when *he **came***.

That is, *when he came*, I said *something*.  This is OK.

If the order of the events is different, and in an hour from the time of "my saying *something*", he will come to the place, then to describe *his future coming*, the Past-In-Future (formed by use of Present) should be used, i.e. "*he **comes***".

Comment: I see your name is Russian... The translate of this sentense in the book is such: "Я сказал, что я (уже) буду писать это письмо час, когда он придёт". So it is the second variant and the  `comes` must be instead of `came`. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, certainly.